# Why is this function header not optimal

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

A little background on the project.
Class Book -> Contain book information
Class BooksDB -> Database for books where books can be Added/Removed/Searched....

Now I've got the following function header which prints books placed in BooksDB vector of books.

```
void printBookDetails(const std::vector<Book*>& books)
```

This function recieves vector of pointers of books as const reference, copies it into a new vector of the same type. Sorts the new vector according to books unique ISBN and prints them.

I am asked now why is the function header above not optimal in the way it receives the parameters, how should it be rewritten and why this function header was chosen instead.

I would love for an advice since I already read everything on SO that can be found about passing objects to functions and can't manage figure this out..

Comment: Well if you are going to make a copy anyways in the function why not just pass by value?  It will save you a line of code.

Comment: Makes sense. But then what advantage does this function header has on pass by value?

Comment: The vector is of pointers, so even with thousands or even millions of entries, I strongly suspect that the copying of the vector is negligible in comparison with the actual print (which does string formatting and I/O)

Comment: Passing by value: not only will it save you a line of code, it will actually allow for copy elision/move constructors, while your code does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `printBookDetails` if you are going to make a copy of the vector then you can just change it to

```
void printBookDetails(std::vector<Book*> books)
```

And let the copy get generated for you.  This saves you from doing it in the function.

Another benefit is that if an r-value is passed to the function move semantics should kick in which saves you the cost of even copying the vector.

Comment: Yet, why was it preferred to stick with the const-reference header?

Comment: @Elia: You tell us. It just seems wrong from what you've told us. There's no reason to pass by reference if you just copy the reference and never use it.

Comment: @Elia It is preferred if you are not going to make a copy as copying a vector can be expensive.  If you are always going to make a copy then passing by value is fine as a copy is made no matter what.

Comment: After digging around for some more, could adding a 'const' at the end of the function help making it more convenient for the user to understand how the function works?

Comment: @Elia adding `const` after a function only works with member functions.  That tells the programmer and compiler that this function will not modify the object that called the function.  You cannot use it with non class functions.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think i'm going to use what you said and add to it that IF it had been a class member function, adding 'const' at the end of the function header would also be an option. - Thank you.

Comment: Personally I still like taking by `const`-ref because otherwise I'm leaking details of my implementation into my interface. But sadly that's not possible if allowing move semantics is a must.